# How to move multiple DOM elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have the following code:

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="description"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>

<div class="product">
    <div class="description"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>

<div class="product">
    <div class="description"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

And Im trying to select all .image elements and move them before each .product element.

When I use the following command, it takes all the images and moves them before the first .product. Im stuck, I tried a foreach - that didnt seem to work.

```
$('.product').before($('.image'));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.image').each(
    function(){
        $(this).insertBefore($(this).closest('.product'));
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xRqcL/).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)

Answer (score 4):

I think this may work too:

```
$('.product').each(function (index) {
    $(this).before($('.image').eq(index));
});
```

Comment: I'm having trouble visualising how that works...off to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/before/) for me! Also, welcome to Stack Overflow, and may I offer you your first +1? =)